# Is summary feature supported on ExtJS 4.2.5 for TreePanel's?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Context: I'm upgrading an application from 4.1.1 to 4.2.5 I've gone successfully to 4.1.3 but when upgrading to 4.2.5 ...

I noticed an issue with the **summary feature on treepanel's** and based on what I see on this thread https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264726-Summary-feature-doesn-t-work-with-TreePanel Evan Trimboli is saying this feature is not intended for treepanels but then again it worked on previous versions.

Ultimately there is an error accessing childNodes of null:

```
  collectNodes: function(targetEl) {
        this.all.fill(this.getNodeContainer().childNodes, this.all.startIndex);
    },
```

So: **Is summary feature supported on ExtJS 4.2.5 for TreePanel's ?**

*I'll try the overrides provided on the Sencha forum and post how it went for me, I just wanted to have this issue also in SO and see if someone else faced this issue too.*

Comment: Thanks, and by the way the suggested overrides on the Sencha forum are not fixing my particular problem. I think for now I'll have the BE send the totals.

Comment: You could add a new item to the store with the summary results you want. Simply put a new record to the store with every load/reload as bandaid fix.

Comment: yeah there is also that option @Tyr, thanks